# django name render is not defined

Tags: django

I have an error when I try to import render in my program and I fear it is because it is not supported in `django 1.9`.
I am using `python 3.4` and `django 1.9`.
When I try to run my server, I have the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name render`.

Here is my code:

blog/views:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render

def date_actuelle(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/date.html', {'date': datetime.now()})


def addition(request, nombre1, nombre2):   
    total = int(nombre1) + int(nombre2)

    # Retourne nombre1, nombre2 et la somme des deux au tpl
    return render(request, 'blog/addition.html', locals())
```

blog/urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  #  url(r'^accueil/$', views.home),
  #  url(r'^article/(?P<id_article>\d+)$', views.view_article),
  #  url(r'^article/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})$', views.list_articles),
  #  url(r'^redirection$', views.view_redirection),
    url(r'^date/$', views.date_actuelle),
    url(r'^addition/(?P<nombre1>\d+)/(?P<nombre2>\d+)/$', views.addition),
]
```

creps_bretonnes.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

I  have also tried from django.shortcuts import *, then the server is launched but when I try to access the page it says NameError: name 'render' is not defined.
Would you have an idea?

What is written on the server when I run it:

[cmd values when trying to run the server with from django.shortcuts import render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV2dC.jpg)

traceback when using from django.shortcuts import * and trying to access    localhost:8000/blog/date

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/blog/date/

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 3.4.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in             get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sperney\Documents\Travail\creps_bretonnes\blog\views.py" in date_actuelle
  37.     return render(request, 'blog/date.html', {'date': datetime.now()})

Exception Type: NameError at /blog/date/
Exception Value: name 'render' is not defined
```

here it is:

```
    """
This module collects helper functions and classes that "span" multiple levels
of MVC. In other words, these functions/classes introduce controlled coupling
for convenience's sake.
"""

from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.db.models.manager import Manager
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.core import urlresolvers

def render_to_response(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns a HttpResponse whose content is filled with the result of calling
    django.template.loader.render_to_string() with the passed arguments.
    """
    httpresponse_kwargs = {'mimetype': kwargs.pop('mimetype', None)}
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)

def redirect(to, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns an HttpResponseRedirect to the apropriate URL for the arguments
    passed.

    The arguments could be:

        * A model: the model's `get_absolute_url()` function will be called.

        * A view name, possibly with arguments: `urlresolvers.reverse()` will
          be used to reverse-resolve the name.

        * A URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.

    By default issues a temporary redirect; pass permanent=True to issue a
permanent redirect
    """
    if kwargs.pop('permanent', False):
        redirect_class = HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
    else:
        redirect_class = HttpResponseRedirect

    # If it's a model, use get_absolute_url()
    if hasattr(to, 'get_absolute_url'):
        return redirect_class(to.get_absolute_url())

    # Next try a reverse URL resolution.
    try:
        return redirect_class(urlresolvers.reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs))
    except urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch:
        # If this is a callable, re-raise.
        if callable(to):
            raise
        # If this doesn't "feel" like a URL, re-raise.
        if '/' not in to and '.' not in to:
            raise

    # Finally, fall back and assume it's a URL
    return redirect_class(to)

def _get_queryset(klass):
    """
    Returns a QuerySet from a Model, Manager, or QuerySet. Created to make
    get_object_or_404 and get_list_or_404 more DRY.
    """
    if isinstance(klass, QuerySet):
        return klass
    elif isinstance(klass, Manager):
        manager = klass
    else:
        manager = klass._default_manager
    return manager.all()

def get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Uses get() to return an object, or raises a Http404 exception if the object
    does not exist.

    klass may be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet object. All other passed
    arguments and keyword arguments are used in the get() query.

    Note: Like with get(), an MultipleObjectsReturned will be raised if more     than one
    object is found.
    """
    queryset = _get_queryset(klass)
    try:
        return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' %     queryset.model._meta.object_name)

def get_list_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Uses filter() to return a list of objects, or raise a Http404 exception if
    the list is empty.

    klass may be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet object. All other passed
    arguments and keyword arguments are used in the filter() query.
    """
    queryset = _get_queryset(klass)
    obj_list = list(queryset.filter(*args, **kwargs))
    if not obj_list:
        raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' %     queryset.model._meta.object_name)
    return obj_list
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's definitely supposed to be there in 1.9: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: The `render` shortcut **is** included in Django 1.9 (see the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#example`)). Can you post the full traceback, it might give a hint what is going on.

Comment: not sure how to post the full traceback when using django.shortcuts import render. Did you mean the traceback when using from django.shortcuts import * ?

Comment: The code you have posted here looks ok. The screenshot shows that the `from django.shortcuts import render` is on line 34, so maybe there's something in that module that you haven't shown us. Alternatively, your Django install might have been corrupted somehow.

Comment: you're right but every thing before is commented (with #) It is another part of a tutorial and I wanted to keep it so I just commented it. It worked fine however. I would go for the corrupted django install I guess but all the rest is working fine.

Comment: You could try adding `import django.shortcuts` and `print(django.shortcuts.__file__)` to your `views.py`. You can then look at the file that Django is importing, and see whether it matches the [correct file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/shortcuts.py). If the `print` returns a `pyc` file, look at the `py` file instead.

Comment: the print returns a py file which is quite different from the file you gave me. Not sure what I should do then. I have added the file

Comment: That looks like a really old version of `django.shortcuts` (e.g. 1.2.x). What did `print(django.shortcuts.__file__)` return? Is that file inside the Django installation, or inside your codebase? How did you install Django? Showing the layout of your codebase might help.

Comment: it returns C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py. Not sure what you mean if the file is inside django installation or inside my codebase? To install it I used pip install Django. What do you mean with the codebase? How can I show it?

Comment: hi Alasdais, I have uninstalled django and reinstalled it but I still have the problem... cannot import name render...!

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I have deployed a virtual env (ubuntu) using virtual box. 
I had absolutely no issues on the ubuntu env to deploy it and follow the steps with the exact same code as above!
Thanks for your help anyway!